# How can I set power button (on computer case) to power off system with `systemd`?

Tags: power-management, systemd

How can I set the power button (on my computer case, not keyboard) to power off the system with `systemd` (without `acpid`)?

Answer (score 17):

`systemd` can handle this. I think this is what you need:

Open the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` ([manual](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html)):

- `HandlePowerKey`: action on power key is pressed;
- `HandleSuspendKey`: action on suspend key is pressed.
- `HandleHibernateKey`: action on hibernate key is pressed.
- `HandleLidSwitch`: action when the lid is closed.

The action can be one of `ignore`, `poweroff`, `reboot`, `halt`, `suspend`, `hibernate` or `kexec`.

If no configuration, default values used:

- `HandlePowerKey=poweroff`
- `HandleSuspendKey=suspend`
- `HandleHibernateKey=hibernate`
- `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`

Comment: I think this parameters related with buttons on keyboard ("Power", "Sleep", etc.), isn't it? (Unfortunately, I can't check it now.)

Comment: I'm frustrated. =)

What's the difference? The power button is the button, by which you power on the PC. Anyway, long press of this key would halt PC regardless of OS settings.

Comment: I set all `Handle*Key` to ignore, because button 'Power', 'Sleep' and 'Wake' are placed near arrows and Enter on my keyboard. I can press it by accident. I need to handle power button on *my computer case*.

Comment: Can you provide more info about keys? For example model of keyboard or PC, because I stop understanding of what keys you are talking.

Comment: Look at these photos: [link](http://www.goodexperience.com/blog/broken/images/kbuttons.jpg), [link](http://www.build-your-own-computer.net/image-files/computer-case-outside-front-01.jpg)

Comment: For this to take effect, you need to `systemctl restart systemd-logind` (or `reboot`). This will log you out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it's related with systemd, but on my system that has `acpid` installed, it respond to power button press automatically.

Can be defined through `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` (On Arch Linux)

Comment: It's related with `systemd` because `systemd` replace `acpid`'s functionality. I can use both `systemd` and `acpid` anyway, but I want to use *only* the first one. I have edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to configure that in your BIOS (if it supports it). I don't see how the power button on the case has anything to do with your OS, where a power button on your keyboard does interact with the OS since the OS loads drivers for the keyboard.

Comment: I have seen as pressing power button on case cause correct poweroff of MS Windows. So, generally speaking, OS can handle power button on case.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acpi