# Configure power button - OpenSUSE LEAP 42.1

Tags: gnome, systemd, opensuse

I use the method described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50748/how-can-i-set-power-button-on-computer-case-to-power-off-system-with-systemd) to configure systemd to power off the laptop when the power button is pressed. (I.e., edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.) This worked perfectly with OpenSUSE 13.1, but now that I'm running OpenSUSE LEAP 42.1, it doesn't work any more. When I press the power button, the system hibernates rather than shut down.

I have a sinking feeling that maybe gnome-settings-daemon is getting involved somehow. There's a gsettings schema named `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` which contains a key named `power-button-action`, however the only permissible options are `nothing`, `suspend` or `hibernate`. But I don't want any of those options; I want shutdown!

I did try setting the `active` key to `false` to disable the power-management plugin. That had no effect on anything.

Is there any, *any* way I can convince systemd to show me some debug output, or see what the settings daemon is doing, or just generally *make the power button turn the power off?!*